# Enviar un array mediante eventEmitter?

Tags: angular

Como puedo enviar un array mediante EventEmmitter?

**************** init component 1*************

```
@Output()
    notifyMeets: EventEmitter<any[]> = new EventEmitter();
```

quiero enviar la variable data, data es un array, como lo envio?

```
this.listMeetService.getMeets(this.user.id).pipe(
            mergeMap(data => {
                const observablesList = [];
                this.notifyMeets.emit(data);
                return forkJoin(observablesList);
            })
        ).subscribe((response: any) => {
            this.friends = response[0];
            this.discriminar();
        });
```

trato de obtenerlo en el componente 2

**************** init component 2*************

```
<ion-card-header (notifyMeets)='getNotificationMeet($event)'> Tus Grupos  </ion-card-header>
```

pero creo que nunca llega ya que nunca veo el console

```
getNotificationMeet(evt) {
        console.log('OSOAAAA', evt);
        this.listMeets = evt;
    }
```

los dos componentes esta en el mismo level, son hermanos, deberia usar  @input?

Answer (score 0):

Para tener acceso a un componente desde otro componente debes instanciarlo. La forma de instanciarlo para poder usa @Input y @Output es a traves de su selector, el cual se define en la propiedad selector del decorador @Component:

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-content', //Esta de aqui
  templateUrl: 'content.html'
})
```

Si tienes dos componentes, un "padre" y un "hijo" :

**COMPONENTE PADRE**

TS:

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'padre',
  templateUrl: 'content.html'
})
export class Padre {
misAmigos: number = 100
//constructor
 getAmigos(datos){
  console.log("Yo y mi hijo tenemos estos amigos", datos)
}
}
```

HTML:

```
<hijo [amigos]="misAmigos" (devuelveAmigos)="getAmigos($event)"> </hijo>
```

**COMPONENTE HIJO**

TS:

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'hijo',
  templateUrl: 'content.html'
})
export class Hijo{
@Input() amigosPadre: number;
@Output() devuelveAmigos: EventEmitter = new EventEmmiter();
amigosHijo : number = 50;
constructor(){
this.devuelveAmigos.emit(this.amigosPadre + this.amigosHijo)
}
}
```

También es necesario que los dos componentes estén dados de alta en el mismo modulo, en el array de "declarations".